# issue with cancelling bubbleing in different browsers in js

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Event Phases</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frm" onclick="frmClick()" >
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Button" onclick="btnClick(event)" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
document.onclick = function()
{
    window.alert("Document clicked!");
};
function btnClick(e)
{
    if (window.event) {
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    else {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    window.alert("Button clicked!");
}
function frmClick()
{
    window.alert("Form clicked!");
}</script>
```

Above code is from: http://triaslama.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/javascript-event-phases-capturing-and-bubbling/

Question:

1. `if (window.event) {}`, is this line only for IE? why we can use this line to detect IE?
2. `e.stopPropagation();` is this line for other browsers(firefox, safari...) except IE?

Comment: yes, that's for IE, but it will also detect Chrome. It would be better if you did `e = e || window.event;` and then `if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); else e.cancelBubble = true;`

Comment: what does this line mean: `e = e || window.event;`?

Comment: If the `e` parameter was passed an event object, it'll just be assigned right back to the same parameter, but if not, the `window.event` will be assigned. So basically it tries to use `e`, and if it's not there, it looks for `event`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/JD7Wu/

This uses event.preventDefault(), which 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

HTML:

```
<form id="frm" onclick="frmClick()" >
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Button" onclick="btnClick(event)" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.onclick = function()
{
    window.alert("Document clicked!");
};
function btnClick(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert("Button clicked!");
}
function frmClick()
{
    window.alert("Form clicked!");
}
```